# Laravel 5 - Strange behaviours looping collection in View

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I pass my view a collection.  If I output this as an array, I get something like this

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:8 [▼
    "id" => "53"
    "name" => "creativeOption"
    "label" => "checkboxSelection"
    "value" => "Animated GIF"
    "campaignCreativesId" => "21"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "created_at" => "2016-03-01 13:52:36"
    "updated_at" => "2016-03-01 13:52:36"
  ]
  1 => array:8 [▼
    "id" => "54"
    "name" => "creativeOption"
    "label" => "Other"
    "value" => "12345"
    "campaignCreativesId" => "21"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "created_at" => "2016-03-01 13:52:36"
    "updated_at" => "2016-03-01 13:52:36"
  ]
]
```

Basically, I have a few checkbox selections.  If the Other checkbox is checked, a text area is displayed to get more details.  In my view, I do the following

```
@foreach($campaign->campaignCreatives->campaignCreativesData as $data)
    @if($data->label == 'Other')
        {{dd($data->value)}}
        <div class="col-md-12 noPadding" id="cOtherText">
            {!! Form::textarea('otherInput', $data->value, array('placeholder' => 'Please provide some additional information')) !!}
        </div>
    @else
        <div class="col-md-12 noPadding" id="cOtherText">
            {!! Form::textarea('otherInput', null, array('placeholder' => 'TEST')) !!}
        </div>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

What I essentially do is check to see if there is a label named Other for this collection.  If there is, I want to display the text area with the old input.  If there is no label called Other, I just need a blank textarea displayed.

Now with the above, you can see I have placed a dd within the if statement.  This is what I am finding strange.  With the above array/collection, the if should be used because there is a label called Other present.  As I would expect, the dd is fired.  The dd outputs "12345" which is the data which was previously added to this textarea.  So if I remove this dd, I would expect the textarea to display with 12345 within it.

However, I seem to be displayed the textarea in the else statement.  Reason I know that this textarea is being displayed is because I set the placeholder to TEST and this is what I see within the textarea.

So even though the if statement is satisfied, why does it display the second textarea?

Comment: The code seems to be right. Did you try to use `@if($data->label === "Other")` ?

Comment: Yes, for some reason the same result.  How can both conditions be satisfied?  Does not seem to make sense

Comment: Actually, I've tested this code here, and I seems to work well... If you `{{ dd($data) }}` before `@if`, what does it print?

Comment: Is the textarea in the else statement printed twice?

Comment: I think I know what it is - not too sure how to solve it though.  So you see my collection contains 2 Objects.  It loops the first Object, its label is not "Other", so it displays the else.  It then loops the second, where it is "Other", so it does the if

Comment: So, it is printing two textareas, one in else statement and one in if statement?

Comment: Seems like it from what I can see

Comment: @kate thats the problem

Comment: And what's the behavior you want? To show only what is 'Other'?

Comment: If there is an Other, it should display the text area in the if statement, nothing else.  Otherwise, it should only display the default textarea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood what you need, I would try to do something like this:

```
@if ($campaign->campaignCreatives->campaignCreativesData->contains('label', 'Other'))
    <div class="col-md-12 noPadding" id="cOtherText">
        {!! Form::textarea('otherInput', 
                      $campaign->campaignCreatives->campaignCreativesData->where('label', 'Other')->first()->value, 
                      array('placeholder' => 'Please provide some additional information')) !!}
    </div>
;
@else
    <div class="col-md-12 noPadding" id="cOtherText">
        {!! Form::textarea('otherInput', null, array('placeholder' => 'TEST')) !!}
    </div>
@endif
```

I didn't test it yet, so, tell me if it works.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly.  Funny enough I had just came up with my own solution a few minutes ago, but it was more lengthy than what you provided.  Thanks

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you! :)